# the official name of this programming approach to compute the union and the intersection

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, set, bit-fields

I [surely re] invented this [wheel] when I wanted to compute the union and the intersection and diff of two sets (stored as lists) at the same time. Initial code (not the tightest):

```
dct = {}
for a in lst1:
  dct[a] = 1
for b in lst2:
  if b in dct:
    dct[b] -= 1
  else:
    dct[b] = -1

union = [k for k in dct]
inter = [k for k in dct if dct[k] == 0]
oneminustwo = [k for k in dct if dct[k] ==  1]
twominusone = [k for k in dct if dct[k] ==  -1]
```

Then I realized that I should use 00, 01, 10, and 11 instead of -1, 1, 0, ...
So, a bit at position n indicates membership in set n.

This can be generalized to up to 32 sets using an 32-bit int, or to any number of sets using a bitarray, or a string. So, you pre-compute this dictionary once, and then use very fast O(n) queries to extract elements of interest. For instance, all 1s means intersection of all sets. All 0s is a special one - will not occur.

Anyhow, this is not to toot my own horn. This surely was invented before and has a name. What is it called? Is this approach used in databases somewhere?

Comment: This is not an answer, but... surely `import sets` would have been an option here?

Comment: No need to `import sets` anymore. `set` s are builtins.

Comment: Yeah, sets are good. `one = set(lst1); two = set(lst2); union = one | two; inter = one & two`.

Comment: And believe it or not `oneminustwo = one - two`.

Comment: I think there's a missing - in the last line of code.  Currently the last two lines calculate the same list.

Comment: "This surely was invented before and has a name."  Clarify "this", please; I think we have 4 answers and 4 different interpretations on what you mean.

Comment: This is the same concept behind Java's `EnumSet`: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html The documentation for that class uses the term "bit vector" as some of the answers below indicate.

Comment: @Jason, ets are great, but think about the running time.

Comment: @Ipthnc: I would expect the set operations to be faster, mainly because they're implemented in C. I haven't measured it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is sometimes used in databases, for example PostgreSQL. As mentions Wikipedia:

> Some database systems that do not
>   offer persistent bitmap indexes use
>   bitmaps internally to speed up query
>   processing. For example, PostgreSQL
>   versions 8.1 and later implement a
>   "bitmap index scan" optimization to
>   speed up arbitrarily complex logical
>   operations between available indexes
>   on a single table.

(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index)

Answer (score 7):

Using an N bit integer to represent N booleans is a special case of the data structure known as a **perfect hash table**.  Notice you're explicitly using dicts (which are general hash tables) in the idea that prompted you to think about bitsets.  It's a hash table because you use hashes to find a value, and it's perfect because you never have collisions.  The special case is because of how the table is packed and stored.

Formulate the hash function, which shows how it's different from an array:

```
int bitset_hash(int n) {
  // domain of this function is only non-negative ints
  return 1 << n;
}
```

Notice bitset_hash(3) is 0b1000, which corresponds to the 4th item (offset/index 3) when using a C int and bitwise operations.  (Because of the storage implementation detail, bitwise operations are also used to manipulate a specific item from the hash.)

Extending the approach to use bitwise-and/-or/-xor for set operations is [common](http://bit-player.org/2009/the-17x17-challenge), and doesn't require any special name other than "set operations" or, if you need a buzzword, "set theory".

Finally, here's another example use of it in a [prime sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (I've used this code on Project Euler solutions):

```
class Sieve(object):
  def __init__(self, stop):
    self.stop = stop
    self.data = [0] * (stop // 32 // 2 + 1)
    self.len = 1 if stop >= 2 else 0
    for n in xrange(3, stop, 2):
      if self[n]:
        self.len += 1
        for n2 in xrange(n * 3, stop, n * 2):
          self[n2] = False

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    assert idx >= 2
    if idx % 2 == 0:
      return idx == 2
    int_n, bit_n = divmod(idx // 2, 32)
    return not bool(self.data[int_n] & (1 << bit_n))

  def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
    assert idx >= 2 and idx % 2 != 0
    assert value is False
    int_n, bit_n = divmod(idx // 2, 32)
    self.data[int_n] |= (1 << bit_n)

  def __len__(self):
    return self.len

  def __iter__(self):
    yield 2
    for n in xrange(3, self.stop, 2):
      if self[n]:
        yield n
```

Comment: You explained the idea in detail, so I should explain why I think it doesn't fly. In any hash table there's a flat array and a hash function. If we take your definitions, the hash function is `(1 <<)`.. which would make the array lookup operation `&`, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I did call it a special case due to exactly how it's stored.  In a non-perfect hash table, which is most common, I wouldn't call the collision resolution a "flat array", even though an array is commonly used, as there's much more going on.  To me that's an implementation detail anyway, and it's the fast lookup of values from hash(key) that's the important part of the definition. -- Though I just realized that if you "take my definitions", you get them all and there's thus no problem. :)

Comment: I didn't say the collision resolution was a flat array. That makes no sense.

Comment: *"it's the fast lookup of values from hash(key) that's the important part of the definition"* So your definition of a hash table is "any data structure with fast lookup based on hash(key)". I think this is too loose a definition because, as you've demonstrated, you can point to any intermediate result of the lookup algorithm and call it a hash code. Under your definition, a simple array is a hash table with hash(idx) = (addr + idx * size).

Comment: More precisely, you were completely ignoring collisions.  The popular array-of-linked-lists implementation, for example, *is not a flat array*.  And no, if you want to stretch things that way, a simple array would be a hash table with an identity hash function---which is only a hash function in the most basic sense.  Please don't put words in my mouth, as I never said emphasized *any data structure* like that, just that fast lookup from keys is *more* important than implementation issues.

Comment: An array is a special case of a dictionary (or, alternatively, a dictionary is a generalization of array).  Dictionaries are often implemented using hash tables.  Therefore, it's not a huge stretch to call an array a special case of hash table.

Comment: Roger: I didn't mean to put words in your mouth, just understand what you were saying. Cheers!

Comment: I think it clearly is a special case of a perfect hash table.  I also think it's not a particularly useful description -- it's more directly a special case of an array.

Answer (score 2):

It's very common to use an integer to represent a set of small integers; it's often called a *bitset* or *bitvector*. Here you're using an integer to represent "the set of input sequences that contain this value".

The operation you're doing reminds me of **reversing a multimap**.

In your case, the input is a list of lists:

```
[["a", "b"], ["a", "c", "d"]]
```

But you could instead think of it as a bag of ordered pairs, like this:

```
0, "a"
0, "b"
1, "a"
1, "c"
1, "d"
```

You're simply constructing a table that contains the reversed pairs

```
"a", 0
"b", 0
"a", 1
"c", 1
"d", 1
```

which looks like this:

```
{"a": [0, 1],
 "b": [0],
 "c": [1],
 "d": [1]}
```

and you happen to be representing those arrays of integers using bitvectors.

The original data structure (the list of lists) made it easy to iterate over all values for a given list. The reversed data structure (the dictionary of lists) makes it easy to find all lists that have a given value.